# Object orientation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am trying to obtain the orientation of features from one of my layers. I have already managed with the minimum bounding geometry tool, by choosing the rectangle by width option. That creates a rectangle englobing my features which has among its attributes the orientation of the longer side of the rectangle.

The problem is that my features are animals, and this option does not allow to recognize one side of them (the head) as the one that determines the orientation. So the orientation that is selected from the two possible ones for each rectangle is up to ArcGIS Pro.

Is there was a more complete tool to obtain the orientation of objects in ArcGIS Pro?

There's picture of the original image in Google Earth Engine with the manatee in question. I obtained from Google Earth Engine the features recognized and then opened that layer in ArcGIS Pro (see picture).

The last picture is the rectangle by width, which gives me the 77º orientation, but that is the orientation of the tail of the manatee, not its head.

Perhaps ArcGIS Pro has some tool that recognizes the pointy end of objects as the one that carries its orientation.

[image: original image]

[image: features in ArcGIS Pro]

[image: rectangle by width]

Comment: I feel like the solution has to be in the object detection from raster, not in an analysis of the derived polygons

Comment: So are all Manatee polygons that tear drop shape? Do all Manatee polygons have an obvious pointy end? Do all Manatee polygons generate rectangular shapes when the extent is computed? I can think of a potential solution if you answer these questions

Comment: Yes, all manatee polygons generate a tear drop shape if the segmentation is well done. That gives you a pointy end to the side of the head. And the polygons always generate a rectangle in the rectangle by width option from the minimum bounding geometry tool. Any recommendations would be appreciated. Thanks.